# setLargeIcon() in NotificationCompat.Builder not working

Tags: java, android, api, youtube

Working with the YouTube API, when I call:

`new DownloadImageTask(activity, i, notificationDetails).execute(notificationDetails.get(i).getThumbUri())`

for this class:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private int currentIndex;
private LoginActivity activity;
private ArrayList<VideoData> notifyDetails;
private String urlDisplay;

public DownloadImageTask(LoginActivity activity, int notificationDetailsIndex, ArrayList<VideoData> notificationDetails){
    currentIndex = notificationDetailsIndex;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.notifyDetails = notificationDetails;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
        urlDisplay = urls[0];           
        Bitmap image = null;
        InputStream in = null;

        try{
            in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Error decoding bitmap", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }finally{
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){
    Log.d("bitmap value", String.valueOf(image))     
    VideoData video = notifyDetails.get(currentIndex);           
    activity.notificationBuilder(video.getTitle(), video.getVideoChannelTitle(), image);
        }
    }
}
```

The Log.d() method in onPostExecute() returns something like:

```
D/bitmap value﹕ android.graphics.Bitmap@41180d60
```

I want to set a notification with a large icon, but it is not working.
Here is the notification method in Activity class:

```
public void notificationBuilder(String videoTitle, String channelTitle, Bitmap largeBitmap){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        Log.d("Bitmapdrawable set", ""+ String.valueOf(largeBitmap));
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(largeBitmap)
                .setContentTitle(channelTitle + " uploaded a video")
                .setContentText(videoTitle);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);               
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);            
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(LoginActivity.class);            
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

The error below that I get in logcat shows "ignoring notification with icon==0", even though the third line of the notificationBuilder() method: (`Log.d("Bitmapdrawable set", ""+ String.valueOf(largeBitmap));` returns: `D/Bitmapdrawable set﹕ android.graphics.Bitmap@41433b80` in logcat.

```
2191-2191/system_process E/NotificationService﹕ Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.myapp/0x109008f vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 kind=[null])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `setSmallIcon()` too.

Comment: From the docs [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Would be nice of Google to put that in the actual method's documentation.

Comment: Its mentioned on the `icon` field of the Notification class. And on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html, but I agrees it's poorly documented for the builders.

Comment: Neither `setSmallIcon` nor `setLargeIcon` are showing in my app when I use RemoteView.